# Can't get url params from ActivatedRoute in Angular 13

Tags: typescript, angular-router, angular13

I am trying to implement nested lazy loading

app-routing.module.ts routes config:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'my-module',
    loadChildren: () => import('./my-module/my-module.module').then((x) => x.MyModuleModule),
  },
];
```

my-module-routing.module.ts config:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'all-pricing',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'all-pricing',
        component: HomeTwoComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'all-pricing/:id',
        component: HomeTwoComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

then in HomeComponent (that has the router-outlet) i am trying to access the param:id from activated route but i get nothing:

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  home: string;
  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
      console.log(event.snapshot.params); // not working
    });
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((param: any) => {
      console.log(param); // not working
    });

    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params); // not working

    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        console.log(val.state.root.firstChild ? .params); // not working
      }
    });
  }
}
```

home.component.html

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Please advise how do I access the params in parent component Home-Component as I needed it to insert it to navigation component